# Function not behaving as my console app did reading service bus queue

Tags: azure, azure-servicebus-queues

I'm hoping not a "dumb" question.

Created console app to post then receive messages from a service bus queue.  works no problem.

Created both a VS Function and one in Azure portal... didn't work.  Unless my console app read one message from that queue.  So if say 5 messages were added the console would get one random one; the function would get the other 4, but NOT until my console app had read at least one... a bit stumped.

Answer (score 0):

seems to be a setting problem between your Azure Function and your Azure Service Bus. I assume your using the Service Bus trigger, so double check if the name you've defined in the function is the same one that lives in the configuration file:

```
using System;

public static void Run(string myQueueItem,
    Int32 deliveryCount,
    DateTime enqueuedTimeUtc,
    string messageId,
    TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info($"C# ServiceBus queue trigger function processed message: {myQueueItem}");

    log.Info($"EnqueuedTimeUtc={enqueuedTimeUtc}");
    log.Info($"DeliveryCount={deliveryCount}");
    log.Info($"MessageId={messageId}");
}
```

function.json

```
{
"bindings": [
    {
    "queueName": "testqueue",
    "connection": "MyServiceBusConnection",
    "name": "myQueueItem",
    "type": "serviceBusTrigger",
    "direction": "in"
    }
],
"disabled": false
}
```

Comment: Thiago, greatly appreciate the idea... will check and post, have a great week-end!

Comment: Checked all is fine... kinda had to be.   Per the behavior, the function does not trigger a read from the queue unless this test console app I've got reads at least one message.  The test app just adds and removes messages as a learning tool... need the function to work!

Comment: try one thing. A restart in you Azure Function App (on azure portal), then, add a new message and see if works